# Python/Mechanize doesn't recognize input form

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize

Newbie here.

I'm trying to mechanize to input text into a search box on a website.

For some reason, it seems like the search box doesn't count as a form.

The "form" looks like this:

```
<th align="left" scope="col"> 
<input type="text" name="searchbox" id="searchboxid" size="40" class="search_box ac_input" autocomplete="off">
```

I get this error message:

```
select_form
    raise FormNotFoundError("no form matching "+description)
```

My code:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import requests
import mechanize
from mechanize._opener import urlopen
from mechanize._form import ParseResponse

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open("theadress.com")

browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser.form["searchbox"] = "input"
browser.submit()
```

I have also tried finding the form by using `browser.select_form[name="searchbox"]` but get the same error message.

Trying to list the forms yields nothing:

```
for form in browser.forms():
    print "Form name:", form.name
    print form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author here. It seems like the form was a javascript. I used Selenium instead to output keys to the form.